# Why weren't everyone on Haruun Kal made a Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi

During the Galactic Republic, every known Force-sensitive is brought into the Jedi Order from infancy. Mace Windu's homeworld, [Haruun Kal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Haruun_Kal/Legends), is notable for having a native population of purely Force-sensitives.

It seems not everyone was made into a Jedi. If that's indeed the case, why wasn't everyone brought into the Jedi Order from infancy? Why, as it appears to be the case, are only some infants, such as Mace Windu, taken?

Comment: Force-sensitives are not just Force-sensitives. Luke's sensitivity to and control of the Force is infinitely superior to Leia's, for example, and some Force-sensitives (like Maz Kanata) don't seem to be able to control the Force at all, only feel it. I don't know much about Haruun Kal, but it seems possible that the majority of the population were of Maz and Leia's type: sensitive to the Force, but not able to control it enough to become a Jedi. No source whatever for this, though, so just a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Perhaps Mace Windu was superior to most of his race in force-sensitivity?

Answer (score 3):

Mace Windu's homeworld was first identified by name in the novel [*Shatterpoint*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shatterpoint_(novel)) according to the ["Appearances" section of the Haruun Kal article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Haruun_Kal/Legends#Appearances), and in that novel this point isn't really explained, although we can make some reasonable guesses based on the information that was presented. The native Force-sensitive human population was called the [Korunnai](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Korun), who were believed to be descended from Jedi who crash-landed on the planet thousands of years ago, and they were said to be a nomadic jungle-dwelling people who avoid settled areas. From chapter 1 of the book (I have a kindle edition so I don't know the page number):

> The indigenous humans live in small seminomadic tribal groups called ghôsh and avoid the settlements, which are maintained by offworlders of a wide variety of species. The Korunnai lump all offworlders and settled folk under the somewhat contemptuous category of Balawai ("downfolk").

It's reasonable to suppose that routine midichlorian testing was only done among settled people on Republic worlds, where there was some kind of local institutional structure that could administer them (any world where new children had to be registered with some administration, like the ones that issue birth certificates in various countries on our world). This was suggested for example by the section on Jedi recruitment in [*The Jedi Path*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_(real-life_book)) (which is Legends, but so is the whole idea that the natives of Haruun Kai were Force-sensitive, which isn't mentioned in the [canon wookieepedia article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Haruun_Kal)), which says on p. 142:

> Locating Force-strong newborns is a straightforward process, at least within the Republic's borders. Mandatory blood tests performed at birth record the concentration of midi-chlorians in an infant's cells, and positive results are forwarded to the Jedi Temple for follow-up.

Another issue is that Jedi only seem to have a legal right to take Force-sensitive children within the Republic's borders (p. 143 of *The Jedi Path* says 'Within the Republic, the Jedi Order has the legal authority to take custody of Force-sensitives'), on a non-Republic world like Haruun Kal they could presumably only do so if they could convince the parents or other caretakers. If a very large fraction of children on this world were highly Force-sensitive it's unlikely the locals would consent to regularly giving up such a large fraction to the Jedi, especially since it's not clear most of the Korunnai had enough contact with the outside world to be familiar with the Jedi, at least not until Mace Windu's student came to the planet on a mission and became a legendary fighter in the war going on there (the plot of *Shatterpoint* revolved around the Mace Windu trying to bring her back). As for how Mace Windu was taken, it's said that his tribe had been in contact with some "Jedi anthropologists" who asked if they could take a single child to train as a Jedi, and were given baby Mace in part because he was an orphan--so it sounds like rather special circumstances, presumably neither visits from Jedi anthropologists nor agreements to give up a single child were routine events on the planet. Here's the relevant quote, also from chapter 1:

> When the Jedi anthropologists were ready to depart, they had asked the elders of ghôsh Windu if they might take with them a child to train in the Jedi arts, thus recovering the Force talents of the Korunnai to serve the peace of the galaxy.
>
> That would be me.
>
> I was an infant, an orphan, called by the name of my ghôsh, for my parents had been taken by the jungle before my naming day. The choice was made for me.

Comment: I didn't know it's not a Republic world...now everything makes sense, lol